# Is it bad to continually increment a counter column in a single row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to keep track of the operations of an application that uses a mysql database mostly read-only. I know that there are a lot better ways to keep track of operational metrics, but as a quick and dirty start would it be horrible to have table with `date` and `hour_of_the_day` columns and then a `count` column to keep track of the occurrences of some event during that hour?

There would be a lot of contention on only a few rows, right? Is this preferable to created in an entire new row per event?

Comment: it depends on data which you need to store/operate and aims that you want to achieve.

Comment: I would consider keeping "correctly normalized data" and "cached data" separate. "cached data" can be built from "correctly normalized data", say via a trigger, DAL business-rules, or periodically (it need not necessarily even be in the same database). That is, *keep the model clean* -- don't let "performance" creep over and pollute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to go this route, which I don't think is a bad idea, you might want to create a new row per event. You can have columns such as `event type` (an ID), `datetime of event`, etc. You could then count the events by doing a `count()` query on a certain event type.

Then you can link it to an EventType table to where you specify what each `event type` is, such as name of event, description, etc